# VBScript create a multi-dimensional array and add to it?

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array, vbscript

This is a doozy for me haha, I've pretty much checked nearly every page on Google Search and I still don't quiet understand how to do it.

I want to create a multi dimensional array in VB Script called data2. 
Trying the examples that I've seen but I'm getting a "Subscript out of range" error

```
Dim data2()

sub grabdata
    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM MSAccess_table"
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    Do Until rsData.EOF = True
        ReDim Preserve data2(UBound(data2) + 1)
        data2(UBound(data2)) = Array(rsData("id"),rsData("column_1"),rsData("column_2"),rsData("column_3"),rsData("column_4"))
    rsData.moveNext 
    Loop
end sub
```

Basically I'm trying to learn how to make a multi-dimensional array in VB script and add to it with a loop. What are some basic examples that can work in my case?

Comment: Please do not use VBScript anymore. Its support officially ended in 2002.

Answer (score 10):

(1) The best way to get an ADO resultset into a two-dimensional array is to use the [.GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Then your problem just vanishes.

(2) There are two kind of arrays in VBScript. **Fixed** arrays are declared by specifying their UBounds:

```
Dim aFix(2, 3)
```

They can't be resized. **Dynamic** arrays can be changed by `ReDim [Preserve]`. The best way to create such an array is

```
ReDim aDyn(2, 3)
```

if you know the starting size, or

```
Dim aDyn : aDyn = Array()
```

if you want to start with an empty one. The catch 22 is: you can use Preserve only for the last dimension.

(3) Your

```
Dim data2()
```

is an abomination - a fixed array of no size. It's a pity that the 'compiler' is too stupid to catch such a beast that VBScript can't handle properly:

```
>> Dim data2()
>> WScript.Echo UBound(data2)
>>
Error Number:       9
Error Description:  Subscript out of range
```

The nastiness of the `Dim a()` statement is hidden by the fact that a later `ReDim` will store a proper **dynamic** array into that variable:

```
>> Dim data2() ' <-- abomination
>> ReDim data2(1,1) ' <-- overwritten by a dynamic array
>> data2(0,0) = 0
>> ReDim Preserve data2(1,5) ' last dimension increased; 'old' data preserved
>> data2(1,5) = 1
>> WScript.Echo data2(0,0), data2(1,5)
>>
0 1
```

**Update wrt jmbpiano's comment:**

(1) I gave evidence that you can't get the UBound for a variable dimmed with (), so I stick to my claim that such beasts are abominations. Just look at the question (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785848/vbscript-pass-for-loop-iterations-into-dynamic-array)) to see that using the () will give you trouble.

(2) I said that you should use `ReDim a(KnownUbound)` to 'declare' a dynamic array with known size, but I didn't give evidence for the 'Option Explicit'-compatibility of this idiom. So :

```
Option Explicit
ReDim a(4711)
ReDim b(4,7,1,1)
a(0) = "qed"
b(0,0,0,0) = "qed"
WScript.Echo b(0,0,0,0)
```

output:

```
cscript 19888987.vbs
qed
```

Comment: "The catch 22 is: you can use Preserve only for the last dimension"; you can overcome that with a dynamic array of dynamic arrays, but is more difficult to keep it clean in your code and to extract the data from: `a = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5),array(6,7,8,9))` now you can get data `a(x)(y)` style: `a(2)(1) -> displays 7`

Comment: The array structure is back to front to that of Javascript. I need data2 to run in a javascript function afterwards.
Why does GetRows organize data in this way? 
data2(0,1) where 0 is the element and 1 is the index

Comment: @Quaking-Mess - there is a toArray method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8943ay3x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but it looses the structure. You shouldn't try to mix languages.

Comment: I think I will try AccessDB a JavaScript Interface Library for Microsoft Access instead.

Comment: "Dim data2()" is just a variable declaration indicating the intended type of the variable (a dynamic array rather than a variant). The only difference being you initialize the resultant variable with a ReDim instead of an assignment.The Dim/ReDim syntax may be slightly awkward (why MS didn't include a keyword to declare a dynamic array with explicit initial dimensions in the a single statement baffles me), but it's hardly an "abomination" and is required if you're using Option Explicit (generally a Good Idea).

Comment: @Ekkehard - I stand corrected. I had tested similar code before posting my comment and had gotten an error when omitting the Dim, but upon testing your code, I see it does indeed work. I must have introduced some other error while doing my test.

Answer (score 2):

This may be off-topic, but after seeing your exact code, why aren't you using the built-in ADO function: [`GetRows()`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp) ?

```
    sub grabdata
        SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM MSAccess_table"
        Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
        If Not rsData.EOF Then aData = rsData.GetRows()         
    end sub
```

This returns all your column # as the first index, and the rows (data) in the second.

So to loop through it, you would:

```
If IsArray(aData) Then
    For x = lBound(aData,2) to uBound(aData,2) 'loops through the rows
        Col1 = aData(0,x)
        Col2 = aData(1,x)
        Col3 = aData(2,x)
        Response.Write "Row #" & x+1 & "<br>"
        Response.Write "This is the data in Column1: " & Col1 & "<br>"
        Response.Write "This is the data in Column2: " & Col2 & "<br>"
        Response.Write "This is the data in Column3: " & Col3 & "<br>"
    Next
End If
```

*NOTE: Rows (and columns) start on 0 in the array by default.

Answer (score -4):

```
set rs = conn.execute(strQry)

arrRAY = rs.GetRows()

if isarray(arrRAY) then
  do stuff
end if
```