# Convert negative numbers from an array to positive numbers

Tags: arrays, vbscript, qtp

I have written a VBscript to find out positive numbers and negative numbers in an array. I have managed to separate and print those numbers. I now want to convert the positive numbers to negative numbers.

This is the vbscript I have written:

```
    Option explicit
    Dim arr(), i, str, number,j,k,str1,p
    number=inputbox("The number of elements the array should have")
    ReDim arr(number-1)

    arr(0)=1
    arr(1)=2
    arr(2)=-4
    arr(3)=6
    arr(4)=-8


    For i=0 to number-1
        If arr(i)>0 Then
            j=i
            str=str&vbnewline&arr(j)&vbnewline
            msgbox ("The positive numbers from the array are " &str)
    end if
    next
    For i=0 to number-1
        If arr(i)<0 Then
             k=i
            str1=str1&vbnewline&arr(k)&vbnewline
            msgbox ("The negative numbers from the array are " &str1)
        End If
        Next

'ReDim preserve arr(6)
    'For i= 5 to 7
        'p=arr(k)*(-1)
        'Next
    'msgbox p
```

The script executes successfully until the second for loop. I am trying to convert the negative numbers from the array to positive numbers(in this case -4, -8). When I execute the commented code, I get only second number "8". I have to show all numbers(positive and converted numbers) together. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, but you are using last entry of negative number in your last commented `for loop`, hence you are missing `-4`. Try something like this:

```
Dim arr()
ReDim arr(5)

arr(0)=1
arr(1)=2
arr(2)=-4
arr(3)=6
arr(4)=-8

For i = 0 to UBound(arr) - 1
    If arr(i) < 0 Then
        Msgbox arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(i)*-1  '<-- This will convert all the negative to positive
    End If
Next

For i = 0 to UBound(arr) - 1
    Msgbox arr(i)
Next
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I don't see anything wrong using this way. And my answer is just an example.

Comment: wrt `Dim arr()` cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/28798878/603855; `ReDim arr(desiredUBound)` is all that's needed. **Understanding** UBound/Last Index vs. Size avoids creating arrays with spurious tails and error prone loop headers like `For i = 0 to UBound(arr) - 1`.

Answer (score -2):

That's how dynamic arrays would like to be treated in VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

' Decent way to initialize a dynamic array
ReDim a(4) ' 5 slots 0 .. 4; no "Dim a()" == spurious creation of an abomination
a(0) =  1
a(1) =  2
a(2) = -4
a(3) =  6
a(4) = -8
WScript.Echo "a =  [" & Join(a) & "]"
Dim b : b = mapFO(a, New cSignSwitch)
WScript.Echo "b =  [" & Join(b) & "]"
WScript.Echo "neg  [" & Join(grepFF(a, GetRef("lessZero"))) & "]"
WScript.Echo "else [" & Join(grepFF(a, GetRef("geZero"))) & "]"
' Convenient way to initialize a dynamic array of Longs
Dim c : c = mapFF(Split("1 2 -4 6 -8"), GetRef("XCLng"))
WScript.Echo "c =  [" & Join(c) & "]"
mapSE c, "a(i) * a(i)"
WScript.Echo "x*x  [" & Join(c) & "]"

' return new array from mapping a's elements via o.map
Function mapFO(a, o)
  Dim t : t = a ' array assignment copies!
  mapSO t, o
  mapFO = t
End Function

' return new array from mapping a's elements via f
Function mapFF(a, f)
  Dim t : t = a ' array assignment copies!
  mapSF t, f
  mapFF = t
End Function

' apply o.map to a's elements
Sub mapSO(a, o)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = o.map(a(i))
  Next
End Sub

' apply f to a's elements
Sub mapSF(a, f)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = f(a(i))
  Next
End Sub

' eval ev for a's elements
Sub mapSE(a, ev)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Eval(ev)
  Next
End Sub

Class cSignSwitch
  Function map(e)
    map = e * -1
  End Function
End Class

' return new array of a's elements satisfying f
Function grepFF(a, f)
  ReDim t(UBound(a)) ' result can't be larger than source
  Dim j : j = -1     ' assume empty result
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      If f(a(i)) Then
         j    = j + 1
         t(j) = a(i)
      End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve t(j)
  grepFF = t
End Function

Function lessZero(n)
  lessZero = (n < 0)
End Function

Function geZero(n)
  geZero = Not lessZero(n)
End Function

Function XCLng(x)
  XCLng = CLng(x)
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 32233658.vbs
a =  [1 2 -4 6 -8]
b =  [-1 -2 4 -6 8]
neg  [-4 -8]
else [1 2 6]
c =  [1 2 -4 6 -8]
x*x  [1 4 16 36 64]
```

Comment: This is not the answer to question.